# Problems installing ADT 9.0.0 on Eclipse 3.6.1 OSX 10.6.6

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I am having a really hard time installing ADT 9.0.0 for Eclipse (plain jane)
3.6.1 on OSX 10.6.6

Here is what I've done:

1. Installed Eclipse 3.6.1 to /Applications/eclipse
2. Updated Eclipse
3. Installed latest Android SDK to /Developer/SDKs/androidSDK
4. Ran "tools/android update sdk" - updated to latest a-ok
5. Followed instructions on official site to install ADT
6. Installing gets stuck on the following url:
   http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xmlfile=/releases/helios/201006230900/aggregate/protocol=httpcountryCode=ustimeZone=-5format=xml

I have tried with older versions of Eclipse and run into the same
issue.

It seems like the URL above works if you insert query string seperators:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xmlfile=/releases/helios/201006230900/aggregate/?protocol=&httpcountryCode=&ustimeZone=-5&format=xml

To confirm I am not bats$%t insane, I did find someone else who [has exactly the same issue](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9a9521eb07c04660), no responses to his query though.

Thanks for any help.

---

```
eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/xxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /
Users/xxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Comment: Just to confirm have you set the SDK location in the preferences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI.. I had this exact problem that occurred only on our company server.  I was stalled on the exact url you mention above.  The admin modified the firewall intrusion detection and the install took-off and completed successfully. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the issue. I had to disable intrusion filters on the ole' asstaro. For some reason it thought it was a windows EMF attack.

Answer (score 0):

In the Add New Software dialog, try disabling the checkbox that says "Contact all update sites..."

It's been my observation the last few months that connections to eclipse.org fail quite often. The P2 update mechanism does not handle disrupted connections gracefully and fails when getting packages. If you've already updated Eclipse, just let ADT install and ignore the other updates for now.